# Is it possible to hide an image on a webpage if the user resizes the window/the window isn't maximized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there some way I can use javascript to hide an img if the user resizes his browser or if the users browser isn't in full screen? 
Something like..

`<script>
    if(window.size != fullscreen)
    document.getElementById('img').style.visibility='hidden';
<script>`

Comment: Using jQuery - $(window).resize(function(){
         document.getElementById('img).style.visibility='hidden';
    });

Comment: why not just apply a css media query like min-width:800px and set display none otherwise? Or is it specifically if they resize - which would trigger if mobile and orientation change

Answer (score 0):

You can use `screen.width` and `screen.height` to get the fullscreen width and height. You can compare those against `window.outerWidth` and `window.outerHeight`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>
    var hideImage=function () {
     if ( screen.availHeight != window.outerHeight ||screen.availWidth != window.outerWidth) //checking that window is not maximized
       document.getElementById('img').style.visibility='hidden';
    };
window.onresize=hideImage();
window.onload=hideImage();
    </script>
```